# creating angular 8 project on windows 10 creates additional files

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular8

Up until a few days ago I have been using an Ubuntu virtual machine as my development environment for Angular and other related projects due to school, however I decided to switch over to windows since I already had node installed along with git and other development tools.

The issue I'm having is when I create an Angular 8 project using the `ng new my-app` command, additional files are being created in the root directory which never happened while I was using Ubuntu. The files that are being created are Command files (.cmd) and Powershell files (.ps1), along with files with no extension.

These are just some of the files that are created: 
[Angular 8 project files on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiX53.png)

If I compare with the file structure of the projects created in Ubuntu (which are the typical angular.json, tslint, etc), I can delete the unnecessary files and the angular app still works. However, whenever I run `npm install` to reinstall the packages due to some error, these excess files are added again and I have to delete them every time.

I have tried uninstalling angular/cli and clearing cache using `npm cache clean --force` and installing angular/cli again but the problem persists. I have also tried removing node and installing it again to no avail.

I'm fairly new to angular and node.js, with only a few months experience from school projects, so I'm currently trying to learn more. I've tried searching using different terms but nobody seems to have encountered a similar problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Reactgular indeed, that has resolved the issue. I guess when I uninstalled it the first time some things were left behind that didn't fix it. Thanks for the help! You can post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the files that are found in the `node_modules/.bin` subfolder after npm install is done.

There is something wrong with your npm install. I would recommend uninstalling node, and making sure everything is removed (path variables, files in your user folder) and then reinstall it.